# MySql Table Structure / Performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, structure

Say I have a MySql database for tracking people. There is a parent table for records of each parent and a child table for records for each child.

I could have a total_children field in the parent table, but then again to get that answer I could simply count how many children records have parent_id of the parent I'm looking for. I hate keeping redundant data, but for certain things having this logged twice may be a performance benefit during certain operations (not having to access the child table every time).

This is a very simple example, but I'm asking this as a bigger picture. I have a good size database (25+ tables with 10,000+ records in multiple tables). Is it standard practice to keep such records in other tables when you could get the same information by executing a more complex select statement?

Comment: 25 tables with 10.000 records in each is a very, very small database. With 100.000 it's very small database. With 1.000.000 - just small database. And even with 10.000.000 records in each table it is still just average, not large database. And not "very large" for sure. So: don't try to do premature optimization. It always causes troubles. Better approach: create two structures and place them as a question. That would me much easier to analyze & answer

Comment: I understand that my database isn't overly impressive or large, I was just wondering if what I described above was something that was standard. I'm in the process of building a web application for a company and I would like to start with an optimized setup, not having to fix it down the road.

Comment: Your current structure description is vague. Your dilemma is classic: _consistency_ versus _accessibility_ as I see i now

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve a problem, or are you just asking if there will be a problem down the road. I don't see any point in storing the child count in the parent table. I can see caching it somewhere if that's a value that you're going to need to pull very often, but the parents table probably isn't the right place. (and you likely don't need to cache it anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is called [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).  Its basically process of systematically breaking the [Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) Rules.

It is fine to do this when you understand the impacts, and it IS a common practice.